# CSS parser in code. overflow-x: none

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to vscode and I am wondering why this editor does not show any kind of indication on a .css file when I place an invalid attribute of none to overflow-x?

When I press CTRL+SPACE nothing is shown, that is great and I can use that to verify.  But I was hoping that this editor has some kind of validation and warning or "squiggly" underline that can happen for developers like most editors might try.

How can I configure this so CSS is parsed with a plugin properly to see errors in CSS so I dont have to look up mozilla web pages of values and can know whether I mis-keyed some value.

Thank you!

Comment: [csstree](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=smelukov.vscode-csstree#overview)?

Comment: If I type overflow-x

Comment: If I type overflow-x: CTRL+SPACE I get the list of available attributes, not including none.  You don't get that?  You say "nothing is shown." Is that just a typo?  If you select from that list you will not mis-key ;}  It will give you warnings on non-existent properties but NOT on attributes - but will show you the available attributes as I said above.  I agree it would be nice if it did both.